# How make java split java with pipe

Tags: java, regex

I have to separate a string into an array that may contain empty spaces, for example,

> |maria|joao|fernando||

but it is ignored when you have space at the end of the line

I am using this `regex split("\\|")`
It should be like it: `maria,joao,fernando,null`
but stays like this: `maria,joao,fernando`

Comment: I'm sorry for language mistakes, i'm brazilian student

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
String str = "|maria|joao|fernando||";
String[] tokens = str.replaceAll("^[|]|[|]$", "").split("[|]", -1));
//=> [maria, joao, fernando, ""]
```

**Steps:**

1. Replace starting and ending `|` using `replaceAll` method to get `maria|joao|fernando|` as input to `split`.
2. Then split it using `split` method with 2nd parameter as `-1` to return empty tokens as well.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add double backslashes to you split string

```
        String s = "|maria|joao|fernando||";
        String [] st =s.split("\\|");
        for (String string : st) {
            System.out.print(string+",");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Java 8 solution

```
    List<String> params = Pattern
            .compile("\\|")
            .splitAsStream("|maria|joao|fernando||")
            .filter(e -> e.trim().length() > 0) // Remove spaces only or empty strings
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```